# Creating class file in a specified directory while using JavaCompiler's run method

Tags: java

I'm trying to run a dynamically created source file using JavaCompiler class utility and it's creating class file in the same directory where the source is located. But, I want to place the class file in a specified directory. How can it be done? Can anyone help me please in this regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

somewhere there should be a command execution for `javac`
right there you need to add option `-d` which sets the output compiled class path

example: `javac -d C:\users\dac\classes MyProgram.java`

this will cause compiled classe(s) to be stored in `C:\users\dac\classes`
read [more on that](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/tooldocs/win32/javac.html)